# create favorites page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to create a Favorites page whereby a user may add a webbrowser's current url to an observablecollection, which may be selected at any time to send the user to that Favorite's url. 
I have tried creating an observablecollection bound to a Listbox which would be populated (at the 0 index) when the user selects to add the current url (on the Main page) to the Favorites page's Listbox. What I have so far is as follows, but is not populating my Listbox and I am unsure of why?

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Opacity=".5" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        ...            
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="add to favorites" Click="AddToFavorites_Click"/>      
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void AddToFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FavoritesPage.xaml?curUrl=" + TheBrowser.currentUrl(), UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

I have created a Favorite class to be used to construct my Favorites observablecollection bound to the Listbox

Favorite.cs

```
  public class Favorite : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //A helper method used by the properties
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    DateTimeOffset modified;
    public DateTimeOffset Modified
    {
        get { return this.modified; }
        set { this.modified = value; OnPropertyChanged("Modified"); }

    }

    //Title for name of Favorite
    //Settings.currentFavorite holds the currentUrl to be used as the title
    string title = Settings.currentFavorite.Value;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return this.title;}
        set { this.title = value; OnPropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }
```

and this Favorite.cs class above is used in my FavoritesPage as follows:

Favorite.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="FavoritesListBox" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             SelectionChanged="FavoritesListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border Margin="24,0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="12"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                               Text="{Binding Modified, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
                               Margin="24,0,0,12"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Favorite.xaml.cs

```
public partial class FavoritesPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //current url from querystring
    string favoriteUrl;

    //temporary state
    public static readonly Setting<int> CurrentFavoritesIndex = new Setting<int>("CurrentFavoritesIndex", -1);

    //the users data
    public static readonly Setting<ObservableCollection<Favorite>> FavoritesList = 
        new Setting<ObservableCollection<Favorite>>("FavoritesList", new ObservableCollection<Favorite>());

    public FavoritesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //this.FavoritesListBox.DataContext = this;

        //bind the favorites list as the data source for the FavoritesListBox
        //this.DataContext = FavoritesList.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //gets the current Url
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("curUrl", out favoriteUrl);
        Settings.currentFavorite.Value = favoriteUrl;

        //clear the selection so selecting the same item twice in a row will still raise the SelectionChanged event
        CurrentFavoritesIndex.Value = -1;
        this.FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

        //bind the favorites list as the data source for the FavoritesListBox
        this.DataContext = FavoritesList.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        //Favorite fav = FavoritesList.Value[CurrentFavoritesIndex.Value];
        //fav.Modified = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }            

    void FavoritesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            //Navigate to the webbrowser page for the selected item
            CurrentFavoritesIndex.Value = FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex;
            //??
            //this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?curUrl=" + FavoritesListBox.), UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

    //private void AddToFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    void AddToFavorites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
        favorite.Modified = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        FavoritesList.Value.Insert(0, favorite);
        //FavoritesList.Value.Add("xxxx");
        //FavoritesList.Value.Insert(0, WebBrowser.SourceProperty.ToString());
    }

}
```

So that is my basic implementation, although I am not sure if it is correct or what I must do to fix it so that it will work properly. I am having trouble will binding the observablecollection to the Listbox and then also with the selectionchanged method which selects the favorite (and its url) at the selected index then navigates back to MainPage.xaml with this url to be used? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am very stuck and new to c#, I'm not quite sure what to do. Please include code help I would greatly appreciate it!! Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up your implementation a little to keep it simple.

I have 2 pages with their associated ViewModels:

**MainPage.xaml.cs** - displays a list of urls in a listbox

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += (s, e) => DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/browser.xaml?url=" + e.AddedItems[0], UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
namespace FavUrl.viewmodels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Urls {
            get { return (App.Current as App).Urls; }
        }
    }
}
```

**browser.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class browser : PhoneApplicationPage {
        private BrowserViewModel _vm;
        public browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += (s, e) => {
                            _vm = new BrowserViewModel();
                            DataContext = _vm;
                      };
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
            string targetUrl = null;
            NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("url", out targetUrl);

            if(targetUrl != null)
                webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(targetUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _vm.AddUrl(webBrowser1.Source.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(tbUrl.Text.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute));
        }
    }
```

**BrowserViewModel.cs**

```
  public class BrowserViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public BrowserViewModel() {

        }

        public void AddUrl(string url)
        {
            (App.Current as App).Urls.Add(url);
        }
    }
```

I have an ObservableCollection that I expose as a property in the App.xaml.cs file.
I access this ObservableCollection from both pages.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Urls { get; set;}
```

I've posted the whole sample solution in a zip file at the following address

http://www.ritzcovan.com/wp-content/zips/FavUrl.zip

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Alex your code worked great in my solution. I do have a question however regarding saving the favorites list to isolated storage so upon closing and restarting the application the favorites list persists. I am using a Settings.cs class with key value pairs which writes to isolated storage but I cannot figure out the best way to save the ObservableCollection of Urls. My format is as follows (for another part) 
`public static readonly Setting<bool> DisableScreenLock = new Setting<bool>("DisableScreenLock", true);` 
Any ideas?

Comment: @Matt, I had a draft post on my blog related to this. Thanks to your question, I posted it.  http://www.ritzcovan.com/2012/03/read-and-write-observablecollectiont-to-isolatedstorage/